# $f(x)=\sin^{-1}(\sin x)$; $x$ is real then prove that $f$ is continuous for all $x$ but not differentiable for all $x =(2k+1)π/2$?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

My attempt is:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f((2k+1)π/2+h) - f((2k+1)π/2)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin^{-1}(\sin((2k+1)π/2+h)-\sin^{-1}(\sin((2k+1)π/2)}{h} =
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{kπ+π/2+h-(2k+1)π/2}{h} =
1$$
Am I right upto this ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What are you using in the second $=$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: using that $f$ is periodic and even (ckeck!), looking at $\pi/2$ is enough.

For $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, $f(x) = x$. For $x > \pi/2$ but *near* to $\pi/2$
 you can check that
$$\sin(x) = \sin(\pi/2 + (x - \pi/2)) = \cdots = \sin(\pi/2 - (x - \pi/2)) = \sin(\pi - x)$$
and using that $\pi - x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$
$$\arcsin(\sin(x)) = \cdots$$
Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

Graph of$sin^-(sinx) $ will help in more understanding.

You can first prove that it is periodic with 2$pi$ and not differentiable at $pi$÷2 and 3$pi$÷2 ....
Then generalise it to$( 2k+1)pi÷2$

*Not the best method.....*

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Elaboration of which part?

Comment: I hope you know how to find period of a function. After finding period check differentiability at points betw [0,2π] ...now use its periodic property to argue that it will not diff. At all such points i.e. generalise

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks